# how to convert json data from string variable to data to display

Tags: java, android, json

i am tring to convert json data from string variable like this example :

```
String in = "{'employees': [{'firstName':'John' , 'lastName':'Doe' },"
                + "{  'firstName' : 'Anna'  ,  'lastName' :'Smith' },"
                + "{  'firstName' : 'Peter'  ,  'lastName' : 'Jones'  }]}";
        try {
            String country = "";
            JSONArray Array = new JSONArray(in);
            for (int i = 0; i < Array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject sys = Array.getJSONObject(i);
                country += "  " + sys.getString("firstName");
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, country, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(this,    e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        };
```

when i try this code i get this error :

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 0 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be   
converted to JSONObject
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your JSON is wrong formated.

Use string as below

```
String in = "{\"employees\": [{\"firstName\": \"John\",\"lastName\": \"Doe\"},{\"firstName\": \"Anna\",\"lastName\": \"Smith\"},{\"firstName\": \"Peter\",\"lastName\": \"Jones\"}]}";

try {
    String country = "";
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(in);

        JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("employees");
        for(int j=0; j <jArray.length(); j++){
            JSONObject sys = jArray.getJSONObject(j);
             country += "  " + sys.getString("firstName");
        }



    Toast.makeText(this, country, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line :

```
JSONArray Array = new JSONArray(in);
```

With this :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(in);
JSONArray Array = new JSONArray(json.getJSONArray("employees"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
JSONObejct j = new JSONObejct(in);
JSONArray Array = j.getJSONArray("employees");
```

note:-

- `{}` denote `JSONObject`. (`{employe}`)
- `[]` denote `JSONArray`. (`employee[]`)

Answer (score 0):

Your String `in` is an object with key `employees` and value `JSONArray`.

So you need to parse `in` as a `JSONObject` and get the `JSONArray` `employees` from that object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String in = "{'employees': [{'firstName':'John' , 'lastName':'Doe' },"
            + "{  'firstName' : 'Anna'  ,  'lastName' :'Smith' },"
            + "{  'firstName' : 'Peter'  ,  'lastName' : 'Jones'  }]}";
    try {
        String country = "";
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(in);

            JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("employees");
            for(int j=0; j <jArray.length(); j++){
                JSONObject sys = jArray.getJSONObject(j);
                 country += "  " + sys.getString("firstName");
            }



        Toast.makeText(this, country, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    };
```